# How to handle wrong chain error [Infura, Wagmi, React, Typescript]

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethers.js, infura, react

When I `npm run dev` and my wallet is **not connected** to one of the chains I have specified, I get the following error

[image]

This raises the question for me, how to handle the error when a user is not connected to the correct chain once we are launched?

This is how I am currently doing the connection:

```
import { WagmiProvider, chain } from 'wagmi';
import { providers } from 'ethers';


const infuraId = process.env.INFURA_ID;

const provider = ({ chainId }: { chainId?: number }) =>
  new providers.InfuraProvider(chainId, infuraId);

const chains: Chain[] = [
  { ...chain.mainnet, name: 'Ethereum' },
  { ...chain.ropsten, name: 'Ropsten' },
];

const wallets = getDefaultWallets({
  chains,
  infuraId,
  appName: 'My App',
  jsonRpcUrl: ({ chainId }) =>
    chains.find(x => x.id === chainId)?.rpcUrls?.[0] ??
    chain.mainnet.rpcUrls[0],
});

const connectors = connectorsForWallets(wallets);

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  return (
      <WagmiProvider autoConnect connectors={connectors} provider={provider}>
        <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
            <Page>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Page>
        </ChakraProvider>
      </WagmiProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```

Everything is working correctly, that error just gets thrown when I run the app and I am not on a supported chain - want to get ahead of it so that the user does not experience a crash or something when they go to the site when it is live.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
  provider = new ethers.InfuraProvider('sepolia', infuraApiKey);
...
//in your React/NextJs:
  const { chain, chains } = useNetwork();//from Wagmi
  if (chain.name.toLowerCase() !== expected_blockchain.toLowerCase()) { ... }
```